# angular 1.5 component wait data

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to use au component in order to display my data.

In my template i have :

```
{{myDatas}}
<my-cmp data="myDatas"></my-cmp>
```

i displayed {{myDatas}} to be sure there was data

here is my code for my component :

```
(function() {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp.test')
    .controller('TestController', TestController)
    .component('myCmp', {
        templateUrl: 'myTemplate.html',
        bindings: {
            data: '='
        },
        controller: myController
    });

    function TestController($scope, $stateParams, ResidencesFactory) {
        $scope.myDatas = TestFactory.read({id: $id});
    }


    function myController($scope) {
        console.log($scope.$ctrl.data.nbElements);   
    }

})();
```

This code doesn't works.
But if i replace $scope.myDatas with the expected JSON, it works.

here is the code of TestFactory :

```
(function () {
'use strict';

angular
    .module('core.test')
    .factory('TestFactory', TestFactory);

function TestFactory($resource) {
    return $resource(
        '/api/test/:id',
        {
            id: '@id'
        },
        {
            query: {
                method: 'GET',
                isArray: true
            },
            read: {
                method: 'GET'
            }
        }
    );
}
```

})();

So i think i have to wait the data from the $resource of my TestFactory but how can i do this ?

Thanks

**EDIT**
here is what i did. i replaced

```
$scope.myDatas = TestFactory.read({id: $id});
```

with

```
TestFactory.read({id: $id}).$promise.then(function(response){
    $scope.myDatas = response;
});
```

And in my component controller, i had the $onInit like this :

```
this.$onInit = function () {
    console.log($scope.$ctrl.data);
    $scope.percent = parseFloat(($scope.$ctrl.data.nbElements/ $scope.$ctrl.data.nbAllElements * 100).toFixed(2))
}
```

But in the chrome console, it tells me that $scope.$ctrl.data is undefined, and the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'nbElements' of undefined

if i do
    console.log($scope.$ctrl);

i have this in chrome console :

```
>myController
    >$onInit: function()
    >data: m
    >__proto__:Object
```

Chrome tell me myCotroller was evaluated so i think myCotroller is not waiting the data before building my properties. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: What's the `TestFactory`? Is it an `async` request? If so this is your problem.

Comment: i added the code of the factory. Yes it makes an async request

Comment: Since you're making a component (as opposed to a directive) I'd also get in the habit of using the `$onInit` lifecycle hook for the controller.  When the constructor is called on the controller, it has not been initialized with the additional scope aspects.

Answer (score 4):

problem solved adding an ng-if condition in my template

```
<my-cmp ng-if="myDatas" data="myDatas"></my-cmp>
```

thanks for your help